# Recursion Trees and Asymptotic Complexity: T(n) = T(n/3) + T(n/2) + n

Tags: algorithm, recursion, big-o, time-complexity, recurrence

I'm trying to use recursion trees to find the asymptotic complexity of this function:

> *T(n) = T(n/3) + T(n/2) + n* if *n > 5*; otherwise *T(n) = 1*

I've made the recursion tree and determined that each level has _(5/6)^k * n_ complexity at each level.  From here I'm not sure how to proceed.  I know I have to figure out the complexity of the depth but aren't really sure how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

As a hint, use the formula for the sum of a geometric series:

> 1 + (5 / 6) + (5 / 6)<sup>2</sup> + (5 / 6)<sup>3</sup> + ... = 1 / (1 - 5/6) = 6

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

These type of recursion can be easily solved using [Akra-Bazzi method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method). In your case `a1=a2=1`, `b1 = 1/3`, `b2=1/2` and `g(n) = n`.

Solving `1/3^p + 1/2^p = 1` your `p=0.7878`. Now you have to solve an integral and you are done.

[image]

This is dominated by `x` and therefore your complexity is `O(n)`